# How to access the single player campaign in Battlefield 3 on PC after previously playing on PS3

Tags: pc, ps3, battlefield-3

I've previously played BF3 on the PS3 and have recently switched to PC and purchased the Premium Edition.

I thought before I go online I'd spend a bit of time in the single player to adjust to the controls.

How do I launch the single player campaign on PC?

My understanding is that I should do it somewhere from the battlelog, but I can't see it anywhere.

[image: Can't find the single player campaign in battelog]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doh, figured it out. I needed to switch from my PS3 to my PC profile.

In my defense, it didn't seem super obvious as I'd tried launching the game from Origin and it defaulted to showing me my PS3 profile.

[image: Switch profile to launch the single player campaign]

Answer (score 0):

this may not be as much of an answer as it is a question,  but did you notice any content difference from PS3 to PC?

P.S. I think i've played you on PS3. Does Mattemmo sound like a familiar username?

Comment: It is more visually impressive on a PC, I don't think anyone would argue that. I had a slight gap between the two platforms and when I first started it up on the PC it all seemed very familiar. I haven't played the same levels yet between the two platforms so it is difficult to draw a comparrison. I got the bundle for PC as I figured it would be cheaper than buying all the individual expansions. So far I'm making all the noob mistakes, such as hitting ~ and then not being able to move as I'm stuck in the console.